# Get ElasticBeanstalk Environment URL in CloudFromation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have set up ElasticBeanstalk using the CloudFromation. Also, I am creating the API gateway with CF. In API I am creating the `GET` method under proxy resource with VPC Link and EndpointURL will be my ElasticBeanstalk environment  URL.
Now the issue is how to get ElasticBeanstalk environment URL in the Endpoint URL.

As per the AWS document ElasticBeanstalk `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` returns EndpointURL.

NOTE: I can't use/execute aws command in the CloudFromation template.

CloudFromation Template.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description:  Elastic Beanstalk and CodeCommit setup

# App stack creation prerequisites:  first create a VPC stack, then a DB stack.

Parameters:

  ApplicationName:
    Description: Name of your application
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

  StackType:
    Description: node or tomcat
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedValues:
      - node
      - tomcat
    ConstraintDescription: Specify node or tomcat

  EnvironmentName:
    Description: Environment name from the drop down.
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod
      - perf
      - qa
      - stage

  ArtifactStoreS3Location:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the S3 bucket to store CodePipeline artificat.

  DevInstanceType:
    Description: The instance type for the dev environment
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    Default: t2.medium

  ProdInstanceType:
    Description: The instance type for the prod environment
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    Default: t2.large

  AutoScalingMinInstanceCount:
    Description: Minimum number of EC2 instances for Auto Scaling
    Type: Number
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 20
    Default: 1
    ConstraintDescription: Specify a number between 1 - 20

  AutoScalingMaxInstanceCount:
    Description: Maximum number of EC2 instances for Auto Scaling
    Type: Number
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 20
    Default: 4
    ConstraintDescription: Specify a number between 1 - 20

  ApiPublicResourceId:
    Description: Id of Api resource id Public
    Type: String

  ApiProtectedResourceId:
    Description: Id of Api resource id Protected
    Type: String

  ApiGatewayID:
    Description: Api Gateway ID 
    Type: String

  CognitoAuthorizerId:
    Description: Cognito Authorizer Id
    Type: String    

Conditions:

  CreateProdEnv: !Equals [ !Ref EnvironmentName, prod ]
  IsDev: !Equals [ !Ref EnvironmentName, dev ]

  Protected: !Or 
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - career
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - course
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - iam
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - job
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - learner
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - resources
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref ApplicationName
      - support                                    

  Public: !Or
    - !Equals
      - !Ref ApplicationName 
      - iam
    - !Equals
      - !Ref ApplicationName 
      - learner
    - !Equals
      - !Ref ApplicationName 
      - resources
    - !Equals
      - !Ref ApplicationName 
      - support      

Mappings:
  # Maps stack type parameter to solution stack name string
  StackMap:
    node:
      stackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.3 running Node.js
    tomcat:
      stackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.2.14 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11
  
  BranchNameEnv:
    dev:
      branch: development
    perf:
      branch: perf
    qa:
      branch: qa
    prod:
      branch: prod
       

Resources:
  ElasticBeanstalkServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
        {
          "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": [ "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com" ]},
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
        }
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkService

  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-eb-${ApplicationName}-service"
      Description: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-eb-${ApplicationName}-service"

  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref Application
      Description: !Ref Application
      SourceBundle: 
        S3Bucket: !Sub ${ArtifactStoreS3Location}
        S3Key: artifacts.zip

  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      EnvironmentName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-eb-${ApplicationName}-service-env"
      ApplicationName: !Ref Application
      TemplateName: !Ref ConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel: !Ref ApplicationVersion
    DependsOn:
      - ConfigurationTemplate
      - ApplicationVersion

  # The configuration template 
  ConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref Application
      SolutionStackName: !FindInMap [ StackMap, !Ref StackType, stackName ]
      OptionSettings:

      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: LoadBalanced

      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: LoadBalancerType
        Value: network

      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: ServiceRole
        Value: !Ref ElasticBeanstalkServiceRole

        # AUTOSCALING OPTIONS
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MinSize
        Value: !Ref AutoScalingMinInstanceCount

      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MaxSize
        Value: !Ref AutoScalingMaxInstanceCount

      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value: !GetAtt "InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId"


      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: InstanceType
        Value: !If [ CreateProdEnv, !Ref ProdInstanceType, !Ref DevInstanceType ]

      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
        Value: !Ref AppInstanceProfile

        # VPC OPTIONS (PLACEMENT OF RESOURCES IN SUBNETS)
      - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
        OptionName: VPCId
        Value: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/VpcId:1}}"

      - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
        OptionName: Subnets
        Value:
          "Fn::Join":
          - ','
          - - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet1:1}}"
            - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet2:1}}"
            - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet3:1}}"

      - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
        OptionName: ELBSubnets
        Value:
          "Fn::Join":
          - ','
          - - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet1:1}}"
            - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet2:1}}"
            - !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/Subnet3:1}}"

        # ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES for jvm options
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
        OptionName: Xmx
        Value: '2048m'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions    
        OptionName: Xms
        Value: '1024m'

      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions    
        OptionName: JVM Options
        Value: '-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false'

        #ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES 

      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: spring.profiles.active
        Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}


# IAM resources
  AppRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole

  AppPolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: App
      Roles:
      - !Ref AppRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"

  AppInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
      - !Ref AppRole

  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-${ApplicationName}-service-instance-sg"
      GroupDescription: !Sub "Security group for the ${EnvironmentName} ${ApplicationName}-service instances"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: "-1"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        Fn::If:
          - IsDev
          -
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: 80
              ToPort: 80
              CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          - Ref: AWS::NoValue
      VpcId: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/VpcId:1}}"

 #CICD for service

 #API Gateway
  VpcLink:
    Condition: Protected
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::VpcLink
    Properties: 
      Name: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-vpclink-apigw-to-${ApplicationName}-service"
      TargetArns:
        - !Join
            - ''
            - - !Sub arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:loadbalancer/net/
              - !Select [0, !Split ["-", !GetAtt Environment.EndpointURL]]
              - '-'
              - !Select [1, !Split ["-", !GetAtt Environment.EndpointURL]]
              - '-'
              - !Select [2, !Split ["-", !GetAtt Environment.EndpointURL]]
              - '/'
              - !Select [3, !Split ["-", !Select [0, !Split [".", !GetAtt Environment.EndpointURL]]]]
   
    DependsOn: 
      - Environment
      - Application       

  #API Gateway Application Protected Resource
  APIGatewayApplicationProtectedResource:
    Condition: Protected
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      ParentId: !Sub ${ApiProtectedResourceId}
      RestApiId: !Sub ${ApiGatewayID}
      PathPart: !Sub ${ApplicationName}
    DependsOn: VpcLink

  APIGatewayProxyProtectedResource:
    Condition: Protected
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      ParentId: !Sub ${APIGatewayApplicationProtectedResource}
      RestApiId: !Sub ${ApiGatewayID}
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
    DependsOn: VpcLink

  ApiGatewayProxyMethod:
    Condition: Protected
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref CognitoAuthorizerId
      HttpMethod: ANY
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "ANY"
        Type: "HTTP_PROXY" # All the requests to the API gateway are forwarded straight to the backend instance via the VPC Link/NLB & the response is sent from the instance. No modifications to the request (query params, body, variables) by API Gateway.
        Uri: !Sub "http://${Environment.EndpointURL}/${ApplicationName}-service/protected/{proxy}"   # Modify uri and add port if necessary
        ConnectionId: !Ref VpcLink
        ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: 'method.request.path.proxy'
          integration.request.header.auth-email: "context.authorizer.claims.email"
          integration.request.header.auth-session-id: "context.authorizer.claims.jti"
          integration.request.header.auth-subject: "context.authorizer.claims.sub"
          integration.request.header.auth-username: "context.authorizer.claims.cognito:username"
          integration.request.header.service-password: !Sub "'{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/CAAP_SERVICE_PASSWORD:1}}'"
          integration.request.header.service-userid: !Sub "'{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/CAAP_SERVICE_USERID:1}}'"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ""
            StatusCode: 200
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
      ResourceId: !Sub ${APIGatewayProxyProtectedResource}
      RestApiId: !Sub ${ApiGatewayID}
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true
    DependsOn: VpcLink

  ApiGatewayOPTIONSMethod:
    Condition: Protected
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      Integration:
        Type: "MOCK"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: "200"
            ResponseParameters: 
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,id-token,access-token,event-type,event-context,stubbed,additional-fields'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'" # Can be modified to specific URLs or domains for increased security
            ResponseTemplates: 
              application/json: ''
            SelectionPattern: ""
        RequestTemplates: 
          application/json: "{\n \"statusCode\": 200\n}"
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: "200"
          ResponseModels: 
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters: 
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
      ResourceId: !Sub ${APIGatewayProxyProtectedResource}
      RestApiId: !Sub ${ApiGatewayID}
    DependsOn: VpcLink


    Condition: Protected
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Sub ${ApiGatewayID}
      StageName: v1
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGatewayProxyMethod 

Outputs:

  Name:
    Description: Elastic Beanstalk Stack Name
    Value: !Ref AWS::StackName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Name

  NLBARN:
    Description: NetworkLoadBalancerArn
    Value: !Ref ConfigurationTemplate

  EnvironmentName:
    Description: Environment Name
    Value: !Sub "${ApplicationName}-${EnvironmentName}"
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-EnvironmentName"

  TypeOfStack:
    Description: Stack type
    Value: !Ref StackType
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-TypeOfStack"
```

In the `ApiGatewayProxyMethod` resource block I want to add ElasticBeanstalk Environment URL at the below line. Currently, I am using a dummy value to create the `method`
`Uri: !Sub "http://${Environment.EndpointURL}/${ApplicationName}-service/protected/{proxy}"   # Modify uri and add port if necessary`

Below is the screenshot. I want the highlighted value.
[image]

Comment: What is your template?

Comment: Here is how: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#EndpointURL-fn::getatt.

Comment: @MarkoE I already went through this document. It returns the load balancer URL i.e load balancer URL. I want the ElasticBeanstalk environment  URL. I have added the screenshot in the description.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, I read the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

Without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) you won't be able to do it reliably. The custom resource would have to be a lambda function that is going to use [describe_environments](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.describe_environments) that returns **CNAME** record for your EB environemnt.